# ATG-Endeca : Wild Card search configuration

Tags: atg, endeca

I am wondering if there is a place where we can configure -- how many characters can be searched on for a wildcard. I am using ATG 10.1.2 and Endeca 3.1.2

Currently I am facing an issue in OOTB CRS application, if I search for one character and a '*' (asterisk), the search returns results, however when I do the same with 3 or more characters from the returned results, no results are returned. It returns again after 5 chars and a *.

I am testing this on the auto suggest feature in CRS, also tested the same on the endeca jspref app, same behavior.

I have searched for any flags that can be used to alter the configuration, but there are none as per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/IAPAdmin/toc.htm#Dgraph%20flags

Help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I found that the wild card search was not enabled at all. The search query reaching the MDEX contained the * but the results only appeared for exact matches or after auto correction.

**FIX**
When I found that wildcard search was not working, I changed my schema.csv to contain the dimensions with wildcardsearch set to true. but that didn't help until I changed my

> fcm.context.xml

changed the part starting with the comment as described below ::

```
<!-- this encodes the property default values from the schema feed xls spreadsheet -->
  <bean id="propertyTemplate" class="com.endeca.itl.fcm.beans.PropertyConfiguration">
    <property name="language" value="${LANGUAGE_ID}" />
    <property name="isSearchable" value="false" />
    <property name="isWildcardSearchable" value="true" />
    <property name="isSortable" value="false" />
    <property name="isFilterable" value="false" />
    <property name="showOnListPage" value="true" />
    <property name="showOnDetailPage" value="true" />
    <property name="enableForRollup" value="false" />
  </bean>
```

now it's working fine.

Comment: What does your Endeca request log say? Do you see the wildcard queries hitting Endeca or do they get lost before that? In the OOTB Auto Suggest Panel there is no configuration for the number of characters to do wildcard searching on.

Comment: Thanks radimpe for your reply, your comment gave me some direction and I was able to narrow down. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Changes done in fcm.context.xml is universal, as it makes *all* the properties as wildcard searchable which might degrade performance.